# bootstrap modal not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

We are currently stuck using bootstrap 2.3.2, and are looking to replace our current dialogs with bootstrap's modals.

I've located all the views where modals need to be instantiated and attempted 2 ways to call them without success.

With JS:

Html:

```
<a title='New Group' class='btn btn-fancy' id="btn-new-group" data-bind="visible: Value() == 'CanCreateNewGroup', click: corp.page.CreateGroupDialog.show">New Group<i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-users"></i></a>
```

JS:

```
define([
'app-utils',
'jquery',
'bootstrap'
], function (utils) {

var CreateGroupDialog = function () {
};

CreateGroupDialog.prototype = $.extend(true, CreateGroupDialog.prototype, {

    show: function (model) {
        var dialog = $('#testing-bootstrap').modal({
            toggle: true,
            show: true,
            keyboard: true
        });
    }
});

return CreateGroupDialog;
});
```

Without JS:

Html:

```
<a data-target="#testing-bootstrap" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-simple show_tooltip" title="Create Group"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus-circle"></i><span>Create Group</span></a>
```

The reason why I have to come here is that I get NO console errors,  NO clue. The JS in my example is being hit,  bootstrap is included and I've stepped through bootstrap code and it is loading my modal's html,  but it is not coming up on the screen in EITHER way, with no console errors.

Actual modal markup (from bootstrap's example)

```
    <div id="testing-bootstrap" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body…</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure how the binding is working in your example - it appears to use the Knockout `data-bind` attribute, but the rest is jQuery. I'm guessing that your `CreateGroupDialog` is not being correctly bound to the modal HTML - especially since you are using require.js. If the HTML without JS does not work either, there could be something else wrong, but I would modify your constructor code to bind to your `<a>` that should trigger the modal.

```
var CreateGroupDialog = function () {
    $( 'a[title="Create Group"]' ).click( $.proxy( this.show, this ) );
};
```

Then instantiate it:

```
var modal = new CreateGroupDialog;
```

Answer (score 0):

The suspected html in the description area of this question was part of an HTML partial which was being called in an area of the application that was not going to be visible then.

If you are using html partials then look into their visibility before doubting the bootstrap modals.  That was my problem.